# VBA loop to show summary without pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problem in crating a loop to have summary on my table data.
To make my question clear refer to below image.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please understand that this is not a free code writing service and show what you already have tried. [Edit] your question and add your code formatted as code block. Explain where you got stuck or got any error messages (and which). Otherwise your question is off-topic ([ask]).

Comment: will paste my code shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably massively overkill but will be quick if you've got a large data set that you're working on (which I'm guessing you are otherwise you could do this easily by hand or using a pivot table). Please have a look at the comments and update where stated. It will currently output to cell `E2` on the activesheet but I recommend updating `ActiveSheet` to your actual sheet name and `E2` to your desired location

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmpArr As Variant
    Dim Dict As Object, tmpDict As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v, key

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Update to your sheet here
    With ActiveSheet
        ' You may need to modify this depending on where you range is stored
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

        tmpArr = rng.Value

        For i = LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1)
            ' Test if value exists in dictionary. If not add and set up the dictionary item
            If Not Dict.exists(tmpArr(i, 1)) Then
                Set tmpDict = Nothing
                Set tmpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                Dict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 1), Item:=tmpDict
            End If
            ' Set nested dictionary to variable so we can edit it
            Set tmpDict = Nothing
            Set tmpDict = Dict(tmpArr(i, 1))

            ' Test if value exists in nested Dictionary, add if not and initiate counter
            If Not tmpDict.exists(tmpArr(i, 2)) Then
                tmpDict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 2), Item:=1
            Else
                ' Increment counter if it already exists
                tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) = tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) + 1
            End If
            ' Write nested Dictionary back to Main dictionary
            Set Dict(tmpArr(i, 1)) = tmpDict
        Next i

        ' Repurpose array for output setting to maximum possible size (helps with speed of code)
        ReDim tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2), LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1))
        ' Set starting counters for array
        i = LBound(tmpArr, 1)
        j = LBound(tmpArr, 2)
        ' Convert dictionary and nested dictionary to flat output
        For Each key In Dict
            tmpArr(j, i) = key
            i = i + 1
            For Each v In Dict(key)
                tmpArr(j, i) = v
                tmpArr(j + 1, i) = Dict(key)(v)
                i = i + 1
            Next v
        Next key
        ' Reshape array to actual size
        ReDim Preserve tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1), LBound(tmpArr, 2) To i - 1)
        ' Change this to the starting cell of your output
        With .Cells(2, 5)
            Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Cells(UBound(tmpArr, 2), UBound(tmpArr, 1))) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Truly massive but useful enough. I will tag this as my answer once tested in my process with this algorithm.

Comment: Works as a diamond!!. Thank you Master VBA.